# How to fix "failed to ensure load balancer" error for nginx ingress

Tags: azure-aks

When setting a new nginx-ingress using helm and a static ip on Azure the nginx controller never gets the static IP assigned. It always says `<pending>`.

I install the helm chart as follows -

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name <my-name> --namespace <my-namespace> --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="<static-ip-address>"
```

It says it installs correctly but there is an error listed as well

> E0411 06:44:17.063913   13264 portforward.go:303] error copying from
>   remote stream to local connection: readfrom tcp4
>   127.0.0.1:57881->127.0.0.1:57886: write tcp4 127.0.0.1:57881->127.0.0.1:57886: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

I then do a `kubectl get all -n <my-namespace>` and everything is listed correctly just with the external IP as `<pending>` for the controller.

I then do a `kubectl describe -n <my-namespace> service/<my-name>-nginx-ingress-controller` and this error is listed under Events -

> Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  11s (x4 over 47s) 
>   service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed
>   to ensure load balancer for service
>   my-namespace/my-name-nginx-ingress-controller: timed out waiting for the
>   condition.

Thank you kindly

Comment: Which resource group does the public IP in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your issue, the possible reason is that your public IP is not in the same resource group and region with the AKS cluster. See the steps in [Create an ingress controller with a static public IP address in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip).

You can get the AKS group through the CLI command like this:

```
az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv
```

When your public IP in a different group and region, then it will give the time out error as you.

Comment: So if I run - az.cmd aks show --resource-group MC_prod_eba-next_prod-eba-next-k8s_westeurope --name ag-prod-eba-next-k8s-static-ip --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv
ERROR: The Resource 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/ag-prod-eba-next-k8s-static-ip' under resource group 'MC_prod_eba-next_prod-eba-next-k8s_westeurope' was not found. - This error appears even though on the Azure dashboard it clearly states that the static ip is in this resource group.

Comment: I am now moving the static ip resource to the same resource group as the cluster using the dashboard. I will post the details of the above command once done. Thanks

Comment: @Koman No, when you create the AKS, there will be two groups, one is for your AKS, and the other one is for the AKS cluster.

Comment: @Koman Take a look at the [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks), it will help you understand the two groups.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I think the problem may be when I created the static ip with this command -  az.cmd network public-ip create --resource-group prod_eba-next --name ag-prod-eba-next-k8s-static-ip --allocation-method static. I don't think I should use the --resource-group flag. As the link you posted says resources should be added to the auto-generated group. Will try recreate now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ingress is in the node resource group, and also that the sku for the ingress is Basic not Standard