# AKS load balancer static IP assignment not working (stays pending)

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have a properly working setup on my AKS cluster where I followed the MS docs to [use a static IP to create an ingress controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip). I have now simply tried to create a similar setup in a separate namespace on the same cluster but the new load balancers `EXTERNAL-IP` remains `<pending>`.

When I examine the service I see:

> Warning  CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  3m29s (x16 over 53m)  service-controller  Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service ingress-dev/dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller: timed out waiting for the condition

I saw [How to fix "failed to ensure lb" error for Nginx ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625051/how-to-fix-failed-to-ensure-load-balancer-error-for-nginx-ingress) but I have all resources (the static IP address) in the same resource group and region as the cluster. The already existing static IP for the LB that's running already is also assigned to the same RG and cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this would be due to the service principal being misconfigured, can you do: `kubectl get events --all-namespaces` and see if you can find anything that relates to the ingress service that would complain about auth\wrong credentials? alternatively you can just [reset service principal credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/aks/update-credentials) in AKS and ensure you got the proper credentials that way.

One more thing you have to ensure is that service principal you are using has right to the resource group where the load balancer is. this should happen by default when you create the cluster, but somebody might have stripped those permissions

just in case comments get deleted: updating AKS to newer version solved this issue

Comment: no aut\wrong messages, just these two:
```ingress-dev   79s         Normal    EnsuringLoadBalancer         service/dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller   Ensuring load balancer
ingress-dev   51m         Warning   CreatingLoadBalancerFailed   service/dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller   Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service ingress-dev/dev-ingress-nginx-ingress-controller: timed out waiting for the condition```

Comment: can you try and create a kubernetes service with a `type` property set to `LoadBalancer` and see if that works?

Comment: tried with the azure-vote-front example from the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard

The error is the same:
2m54s       Normal    EnsuringLoadBalancer         service/azure-vote-front                       Ensuring load balancer
2m54s       Warning   CreatingLoadBalancerFailed   service/azure-vote-front                       Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service ingress-dev/azure-vote-front: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: I'd suggest you reset the SP credentials and verify SP got proper rights. you can assign contributor permissions to SP on the resource group level

Comment: I followed the 'reset sp credentials' instructions from the link you have provided and also assigned that SP to the Contributor Role in the Web UI for the relevant RG. I still don't get public IP addresses assigned for the load balancers. Neither the basic one (azure-vote-front, dynamic IP as per the ms docs) nor the one from the Helm based ingress using a static IP address that I have created already.
This worked all just fine about 2 months ago... :(

Comment: thats really weird. you assigned permissions to the `MC_bla-bla-bla` resource group, right? one more thing you can try - update kubernetes to a newer version. this will redeploy the masters and workers. so if something is stuck somewhere it might get unstuck. I'd also delete all the service objects before doing that

Comment: Phew, that did the trick. Cluster was on 1.14.6 so I had only a beta version to upgrade to but I did it anyway. running 1.15.3 and it works now... re-created the ingress using the same helm chart and settings and the fixed IP address was binding to it within 2 minutes...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

create static IP with "--sku Standard"

```
STATICIP=$(az network public-ip create --resource-group <MC_your-RG> --name Your-public-ip-name --sku Standard --allocation-method static --query publicIp.ipAddress -o tsv)
```

And now:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name 
--namespace 
--set rbac.create=true 
--set controller.replicaCount=2 
--set controller.stats.enabled=true 
--set controller.metrics.enabled=true 
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta.kubernetes.io/os"=linux 
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta.kubernetes.io/os"=linux 
--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy="Local" 
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=${STATICIP}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a kubernetes cluster, Azure automatically creates another resource group to hold the VMs that actually power the cluster. 
I have noticed, if the static IP is created in the same resource group (as the VMs) it begins to work.