# Installing nginx ingress in AKS cluster fails with SyncLoadBalancerFailed error

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an AKS cluster with a web application. I want to provision an nginx Ingress controller to expose the app to the internet and later enable TLS.

I have been following the official documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip

But I always end up with a pending nginx-ingress service with this error

```
reason: SyncLoadBalancerFailed
message: >-
  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: instance not
  found
```

[image]

I have seen

[How to fix "failed to ensure load balancer" error for nginx ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625051/how-to-fix-failed-to-ensure-load-balancer-error-for-nginx-ingress)

and googled the error but so far no luck

Does anyone know what could it be?

Or, is there some working example I can start from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are using a static IP address with the NGINX Ingress controller service. This issue pops up if the cloud controller manager cannot find the static Azure Public Ip Address resource in the containing resource group mentioned in the NGINX Ingress Controller's service annotation (if no resource group is explicitly specified with a service annotation, it will look for the Azure Public IP Address resource in the [AKS cluster's node resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#why-are-two-resource-groups-created-with-aks))

If you have created the static Azure Public IP Address resource in the node resource group then please ensure that the Azure Public IP address resource exists.

If you have created the static Azure Public IP Address resource in a different resource group, then:

- Please ensure the cluster identity used by the AKS cluster has delegated permissions to the other resource group, such as Network Contributor.

  ```
  az role assignment create \
    --assignee <Client ID of cluster identity> \
    --role "Network Contributor" \
    --scope /subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<Public IP address resource group name>
  ```

  **Note:** Your cluster identity can be a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal?tabs=azure-cli) or a [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity).
- In the `helm install` command to deploy an NGINX Ingress Controller, please add the following argument:
  `--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"=$PublicIpAddressResourceGroupName`

  Thus, if you are following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#ip-and-dns-label) the helm install command should look something like:

  ```
  # Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller
  helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.image.image=$CONTROLLER_IMAGE \
    --set controller.image.tag=$CONTROLLER_TAG \
    --set controller.image.digest="" \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.image=$PATCH_IMAGE \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.image.tag=$PATCH_TAG \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.image.registry=$ACR_URL \
    --set defaultBackend.image.image=$DEFAULTBACKEND_IMAGE \
    --set defaultBackend.image.tag=$DEFAULTBACKEND_TAG \
    --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=$STATIC_IP \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"=$DNS_LABEL
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-resource-group"=$PublicIpAddressResourceGroupName
  ```

For more information please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/static-ip#create-a-service-using-the-static-ip-address).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with a non nginx-ingress load balancer in AKS and fixed the issue by **stopping and re-starting the cluster** through the Azure portal.

Spent a lot of time looking for solutions online and didn't find anything that worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).