# Browsing web app hosted in AKS cluster through nginx ingress with TLS endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, https, tls1.2, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

Following

[Installing nginx ingress in AKS cluster fails with SyncLoadBalancerFailed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174737/installing-nginx-ingress-in-aks-cluster-fails-with-syncloadbalancerfailed-error)

I tried to add TLS to the ingress. I followed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls

Everything works as per the documentation, including the curl tests at the end.

My problem is that I expect to be able to browse the application at https://EXTERNAL_IP.

Instead I get

[image]

If I try http I get

[image]

Also note that if I remove from the Ingress the tls related entries

```
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - demo.azure.com
      secretName: aks-ingress-tls
rules:
    - host: demo.azure.com
```

http access works fine

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS wont work with https://EXTERNAL_IP. Certificates only work with domain names, in your case it would be `https://demo.azure.com`.

You also need to trust the certificate authority which created this Fake Certificate with your client or browser.

Here you can read about [TLS/SSL Certificates](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/).